# android, crash on transition for my fragment

Tags: android, navigation, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I have a random crash on my application, and look they are on android internal code. One is:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only TabItem instances can be added to TabLayout
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addViewInternal(TabLayout.java:1606)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addView(TabLayout.java:1589)
        at android.transition.TransitionUtils.createViewBitmap(TransitionUtils.java:192)
        at android.transition.TransitionUtils.copyViewImage(TransitionUtils.java:103)
```

and the other

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: ViewPager2 does not support direct child views
        at androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2.onViewAdded(ViewPager2.java:489)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchViewAdded(ViewGroup.java:5937)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:6119)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5884)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5824)
        at android.transition.TransitionUtils.createViewBitmap(TransitionUtils.java:192)
        at android.transition.TransitionUtils.copyViewImage(TransitionUtils.java:103)
```

none of them looks to be in my code...
has anyone encountered these crashes before?

**Edit:**

the remainder of stacktraces are common:

```
        at android.transition.TransitionUtils.copyViewImage(TransitionUtils.java:103)
        at android.transition.Visibility.onDisappear(Visibility.java:420)
        at android.transition.Visibility.createAnimator(Visibility.java:255)
        at android.transition.Transition.createAnimators(Transition.java:733)
        at android.transition.TransitionSet.createAnimators(TransitionSet.java:444)
        at android.transition.Transition.playTransition(Transition.java:1777)
        at android.transition.TransitionManager$MultiListener.onPreDraw(TransitionManager.java:327)
        at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1124)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3867)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2631)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9978)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1010)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:809)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:744)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:995)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

it happens on android 10 and not on android 7-9, it looks like it is trying to create bitmap of current fragment, but the current fragment contains TabLayout and viewPager and are not supported.
Debugging I see that the invalid view it tries to add on TabLayout is a SlidingTabIndicator, so it looks correct.
Another information, It looks like the crash started when I moved from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar` as base theme of my application

Comment: It looks like the problem is that before exit from fragment it does `tabLayout.visibility = View.GONE` without this, it does not crash, but I have an unaesthetic empty tab layout

Comment: It is clearly a bug on code base of android

Comment: hey @Perry have you resolved the problem?

Comment: I did a workaround: when exit page if the tabLayout is gone then set it to visible

Comment: I also got this issue and solved it with another workaround. You can check it here  :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/68852671/2339405

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given stack traces...

`ViewPager2 does not support direct child views`:
As the error message clearly states, do NOT add fragments directly to ViewPager2.

For example, calling `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace` will not work.
If you want to add `Fragments` to `Viewpagers`, you should use `FragmentStateAdapter` .

`Only TabItem instances can be added to TabLayout`: As the error message states, make sure your TabLayout in XML does NOT have any child other than `TabItem`.

For example this is incorrect:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout">
     <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager /> <!-- This Viewpager should be placed somewhere else. -->
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

Now this is correct:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout">
  <!-- No Child allowed other than TabItem. -->
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

If you think this is not the answer, please provide more details.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You are right, I did not provide enough details. I added some informations