# IllegalArgumentException: Only TabItem instances can be added to TabLayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-databinding, android-tablayout

I have a fragment1 and fragment2.

Fragment1 is landing page of the app and
Fragment2 has ViewPager with TabLayout:

```
        <ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager">
            <TabLayout
                android:visibility="@{viewModel.isTabLayoutVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout />
        </ViewPager>
```

It works as expected until I go back from fragment2 to fragment1. It crashes like in 50% of cases:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only TabItem instances can be added to TabLayout
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addViewInternal(TabLayout.java:1517)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.addView(TabLayout.java:1500)
    at androidx.transition.TransitionUtils.createViewBitmap(TransitionUtils.java:138)
    at androidx.transition.TransitionUtils.copyViewImage(TransitionUtils.java:64)
    at androidx.transition.Visibility.onDisappear(Visibility.java:401)
    at androidx.transition.Visibility.createAnimator(Visibility.java:257)
    at androidx.transition.Transition.createAnimators(Transition.java:747)
    at androidx.transition.TransitionSet.createAnimators(TransitionSet.java:480)
    at androidx.transition.Transition.playTransition(Transition.java:1821)
    at androidx.transition.TransitionManager$MultiListener.onPreDraw(TransitionManager.java:301)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1093)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3094)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1948)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8177)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:972)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:796)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:731)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:957)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

and it it looks not related to my code. Feels like android library is crashing.

But when I remove the visibility condition:

```
    android:visibility="@{viewModel.isTabLayoutVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
```

It works without issues.

Anybody knows what's the problem here?

Comment: How do you navigate back from fragment2 to fragment 1? Is the tab layout view pager present only in fragment 2 layout file?

Comment: correct. tab layout and view pager are placed in fragment 2 only

Comment: I navigate through physical back button

Comment: maybe you can debug the code,  and check what the `child` had been add to `Tablayout`?

`private void addViewInternal(final View child) {
    if (child instanceof TabItem) {
      addTabFromItemView((TabItem) child);
    } else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only TabItem instances can be added to TabLayout");
    }
  }`

Comment: doesn't look like it's debuggable. cannot put breakpoint there. I was able put it on a method declaration but the app freezes min debug mode then.

Comment: Can u share the XML? I think you forgot the `<import type="android.view.View"/>` inside `data` tag?

Comment: I have <import type="android.view.View"/> in xml

Answer (score 1):

I added some logging and found that it crashes when TabLayout receives SlidingTabIndicator in addView method. I'm not sure what caused it but I resolved the crush with workaround:

I created new version of TabLayout and changed addView methods so I could filter all the views different form those which are expected there:

```
    class NewTabLayout : TabLayout {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet) : super(context, attributeSet)
    constructor(context: Context, attributeSet: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) :
        super(context, attributeSet, defStyleAttr)

    override fun addView(child: View?, width: Int, height: Int) {
        if (child is TabItem) {
            super.addView(child, width, height)
        }
    }

    override fun addView(child: View?, width: Int) {
        if (child is TabItem) {
            super.addView(child, width, height)
        }
    }

    override fun addView(child: View?) {
        if (child is TabItem) {
            super.addView(child, width, height)
        }
    }
}
```